# Disable input fields inside non selected div elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have input fields inside a div. I want to disable all the input fields where the div id is not equal to certain variable. For example I have an id == 12, i want to disable all input fields inside the div elements with the id != 12. How to do that in jQuery. Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be something along the lines of `$(input_class[id!="12"]).disable()`

Answer (score 0):

To disable all input elements within div use the following code:

```
$(‘#message :input’).attr(‘disabled’, true);
```

To disable all select elements within div use the following code:

```
$(‘#message :select’).attr(‘disabled’, true);
```

To disable all submit buttons within div use the following code:

```
$(“#message :submit”).attr(“disabled”, “true”);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I disable all input fields inside non #message div?

Comment: Use `not` selector. `$("div:not(#message) :input").attr('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   const elements = jQuery('div.parent > input')
   elements.each(function(inputField){

      const id = this.id;
      this.disabled = parseInt(id) !== 12 ? true: false
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="parent">

  <input type="text" id="1" value="test 1"/> 
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="2" value="test 2"/> 
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="12" value="test 12"/> 
  <br/>

</div>
```

With JavaScript

```js
const parentElement = document.getElementById('parent');
const elements = parentElement.querySelectorAll('input');

//disable input fields having id != 12

elements.forEach(function(inputField){
   const id = inputField.id;
   if(parseInt(id) !== 12){
     inputField.disabled = true
   }
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <input type="text" id="1" value="test 1"/> 
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="2" value="test 2"/> 
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="12" value="test 12"/> 
  <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: Please accept if you are agree with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `not` selector.

```
$("div:not(#message) :input").attr('disabled', true);
```

```js
$("div:not(#message) :input").attr('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">
  <input type="text" value="DIV = MESSAGE ">
</div>
  
<div>
  <input type="text" value="DIV != MESSAGE">
</div>
```